# Firebase query with Async storage

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, ecmascript-6, asyncstorage

I'm trying to use a value from asyncStorage in my firebase query.

I'm feeling stuck on this. I tried with async/await, try/catch, then.

Not sure how I should do this.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
        rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2,
      }),
    };

    const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    if (user != null) {
      AsyncStorage.getItem('parentUid')
        .then((data) => {
          this.setState({ pUID: data });
        });
      this.itemsRef = this.getRef().child(`Stores/${this.state.pUID}/`);
    } else {
      Alert.alert('Error', 'login again!');
    }
    this.connectedRef = firebase.database().ref('.info/connected');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've moved from constructor to react lifecycle, and it's working fine. If someone need, here's the code.

```
  componentWillMount() {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('parentUid')
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({ pUID: data }, () => {
          this.itemsRef = this.getRef().child(`Stores/${this.state.pUID}/`);
        });
      })
      .then(() => {
        this.connectedRef.on('value', this.handleValue);
      });
  }
```